# Using multiple inter-process communication queues in C

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue, interprocess

I am trying to use multiple different message queues in C for communicating between different processes on Linux. I use systemd.

See my code below for one process. Why is it that `msgid1` and `msgid2` are the exact same value in this case?

Doesn't this then mean that the queues are the same?

I would expect that I am creating different queues here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int main()
{
    struct buffer1
    {
        long mesg_type;
        int num;
    }message1;

    struct buffer2
    {
        long mesg_type;
        char text[20];
    }message2;

    key_t key1;
    key_t key2;

    int msgid1;
    int msgid2;

    // ftok to generate unique key
    key1 = ftok("test1",1);
    key2 = ftok("test2",2);

    msgid1 = msgget(key1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msgid2 = msgget(key2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // printf("%d  %d", msgid1 , msgid2 ); -- msgid1  and msgid2 are the same values

    //msgrcv(msgid1, &message1, sizeof(message1), 1, 0);
    //msgrcv(msgid2, &message2, sizeof(message2), 1, 0);
}
```

EDIT : I have removed the error checking on function calls here for simplicity. There are no errors in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What about `key1` and `key2`, or they also identical? Please make a [mre] which demonstrates and provide sample output.

Comment: You should include checking to see if `ftok()` and `msgget()` and other functions return errors.

Comment: @Shawn I am checking for errors. There are none.  I just want to remove them from the program here for simplicity.

Comment: I copied your code, and got `key1 = key2 = -1`, with `errno = No such file or directory`. Then I created `touch test1 test2` and uncommented the `printf`, and run again - it outputted `0 1` for `msgid1, msgid2`. I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. What system are you running on?

Comment: `What system are you running on?` Archlinux linux5.16.15-zen1 gcc11.2.0 glibc2.35